# BlackBerry - Problem with GZip decompression

Tags: blackberry, compression, gzip, magic-numbers

There is a strange problem I've run in using [RIM compression API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/compress/GZIPInputStream.html), I can't make it work as it's described in documentation.
If I gzip plain text file using [win gzip tool](http://www.gzip.org/), add gz to resources of blackberry project and in app try to decompress it, there will be infinite loop, gzis.read() never return -1...

```
try
{
    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.gz");
    GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    char c;
    while ((c = (char)gzis.read()) != -1)           
    {
        sb.append(c);
    }

    String data = sb.toString();
    add(new RichTextField(data));
    gzis.close();
}
catch(IOException ioe)
{
}
```

After the compressed content there is repetition of 65535 value in gzis.read(). The only workaround I've found is dumb

```
while ((c = (char)gzis.read()) != -1 && c != 65535)
```

But I'm curious what is the reason, what I'm doing wrong, and why [65535](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65535_(number))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[char](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) is an unsigned, 16-bit data type.  -1 cast to a char is 65535.

Change to:

```
int i;
while ((i = gzis.read()) != -1)           
{
  sb.append((char)i);
}
```

And it should work.  The example on RIM's API can't possibly work, as no char will ever equal -1.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, RIM demystified! I should be more careful :)

Comment: Omg.. old question, but helped me just today.